# jQuery block text pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any jQuery plugin to take a text block, and split it in multiple pages? I don't have any backend pagination or smth, just a text block and I need a plugin to take that raw text and split it in a few pages and add the pagination links.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849148/counting-divs-for-pagination-in-jquery

Comment: It's not want I want, but it's a start point.10x

Answer (score 0):

1 . You can just cut and recompose your text with plain JavaScript's `.split()` and/or `.slice()`
(do not mix with same jQuery methods which imply to DOM)

for example:

```
firsttag = "<div id='book'><div>";
lasttag = "</div></div>";  

text = "text_separator_text_separator_text_separator_text";   

htmlstring = firsttag + text.split('_separator_').join('</div><div>')+lasttag;
```

2 . And next you will have good chance to use this plugin:
[Easy Paginate - jQuery plugin for pagination](http://cssglobe.com/post/9801/easy-paginate-jquery-plugin-for-pagination)