# How do I add a jquery div counter and then display the div's page total

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Hello I've been trying to work through a problem can find any good tutorials on this nor do I have experience creating pagination that totals div content.

My example I'm using is https://bad.creditloan.com/ which I'm trying to replicate.

I have created the enclosing div's(or div) whatever is the best approach. Preferably a single div which works better for mobile. Currently I used this reference [Counting divs for pagination in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2849148/counting-divs-for-pagination-in-jquery) to add the count which display the count but does not work fully for my task.

Hear is a  screenshot of what I have https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5RrpidpuA44WGtXeVFtYjJQRDQ/edit?usp=sharing so far. What I have is basically a slider with the output of the total divs I'm using. 
To complete this I would just need to ouput the total number of pages and show only the current div's page number.

Here is an example of the code I have:

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var articles = $('section>article');
var now = 0; // currently shown div
articles.hide().first().show();
$("a#next").click(function (e) {
    articles.eq(now).hide();
    now = (now + 1 < articles.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
    articles.eq(now).show(); // show next   
});
$("a#prev").click(function (e) {
    articles.eq(now).hide();
    now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : articles.length - 1;
    articles.eq(now).show(); // or .css('display','block');
    //console.log(articles.length, now);
});

//paginate
// add numbers
$(function() {
    var i = 0;
    $('section>article').each(function (){
        i++;
        $('#paginator').append("<span('"+$(this).attr('id')+"')\">"+i+"</span> ");
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<section><nav><div class="pagination"><span id="paginator"></span> of <span id="pagetotal"></span></div>
            <div id="pagecontrols"><a id="prev">Previous</a> | <a id="next">Next</a></div></nav>
                <article class="at selected">
                    <h2>Payday Loans in the UK</h2>
            <p>An estimated 1.2 million adults in the United Kingdom borrowed a payday loan in 2009, resulting in a total lending of &pound;1.2 billion.<sup>1</sup> IRN Research, a research consultancy service in the UK, believes the number of borrowers could increase by as much as 45 percent in the coming years.<sup>1</sup> So where did this fast-growing industry come from, and how did it expand into the UK? For the answers, we must first look across the pond.</p>
<p>Payday loans originated in the United States in the early 1990s when cheque-cashing firms realised they could earn extra money by giving their customers a way to obtain money in advance of their paycheck. They were so successful that by 1998, payday lending was legal in 32 states. Ten years later, it was legal in 37.<sup>2</sup> By that time, the lending industry had also transitioned primarily from brick-and-mortar stores to the Internet, offering customers the convenience of applying for a payday loan from home.</p>
</article>
<article class="at">
<h2>What are payday loans?</h2>
<p>Sometimes referred to as a cash advance, a payday loan is a short-term loan that is typically repaid on a borrower&rsquo;s next payday. A payday loan is typically used for emergency expenses, particularly auto repair bills or overdue bills. Although online lending has increased in popularity over the last 10 years, there are still many brick-and-mortar businesses that offer payday loans. In storefronts, borrowers usually provide a post-dated cheque to the lender to cover the eventual repayment of the money they borrow, if approved.</p>
<p>Online lenders offer borrowers the convenience of applying from home or on their mobile device. When an online application is submitted, the lender will begin its review process and verify that all of the borrower&rsquo;s information is accurate &mdash; this can take as little as 30 minutes or up to a few days, depending on the lender and the information provided. If a borrower is approved, the lender deposits the loan amount directly into the borrower&rsquo;s bank account. Some lenders promise funds as soon as five minutes, while others can take up to the next business day to fund.</p>
</article>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've spent many hours searching online my nothing puts both counting the divs or breaking up a div and outputting html versus outputting text using  .text or .html and displaying the total count. So the output shows "1 of xx" the current div or split div and the total amount of divs or split divs.

Thanks,

Great help thanks I added this code as you suggested and it worked but one other question though. I added this for the pagination

```
                <article class="at selected page" data-index="1">
                    <h2>Payday Loans in the UK</h2>
            <p>An estimated 1.2 million adults in the United Kingdom borrowed a payday loan in 2009, resulting in a total lending of &pound;1.2 billion.<sup>1</sup> IRN Research, a research consultancy service in the UK, believes the number of borrowers could increase by as much as 45 percent in the coming years.<sup>1</sup> So where did this fast-growing industry come from, and how did it expand into the UK? For the answers, we must first look across the pond.</p>
 <p>Payday loans originated in the United States in the early 1990s when cheque-cashing firms realised they could earn extra money by giving their customers a way to obtain money in advance of their paycheck. They were so successful that by 1998, payday lending was legal in 32 states. Ten years later, it was legal in 37.<sup>2</sup> By that time, the lending industry had also transitioned primarily from brick-and-mortar stores to the Internet, offering customers the convenience of applying for a payday loan from home.</p>
 </article>
 <article class="at page"  data-index="2">
 <h2>What are payday loans?</h2>
 <p>Sometimes referred to as a cash advance, a payday loan is a short-term loan that is typically repaid on a borrower&rsquo;s next payday. A payday loan is typically used for emergency expenses, particularly auto repair bills or overdue bills. Although online lending has increased in popularity over the last 10 years, there are still many brick-and-mortar businesses that offer payday loans. In storefronts, borrowers usually provide a post-dated cheque to the lender to cover the eventual repayment of the money they borrow, if approved.</p>
 <p>Online lenders offer borrowers the convenience of applying from home or on their mobile device. When an online application is submitted, the lender will begin its review process and verify that all of the borrower&rsquo;s information is accurate &mdash; this can take as little as 30 minutes or up to a few days, depending on the lender and the information provided. If a borrower is approved, the lender deposits the loan amount directly into the borrower&rsquo;s bank account. Some lenders promise funds as soon as five minutes, while others can take up to the next business day to fund.</p>
```

Then I added this

```
    // add numbers
$(".pagination > .page").click(function() {
now = $(this).attr("data-index");
```

was this to replace this

```
$(function() {
var i = 0;
$('section>article').each(function (){
    i++;
    $('#paginator').append("<span('"+$(this).attr('id')+"')\">"+i+"</span> ");
});

});
```

Comment: No, you'll need to rewrite the line starting `$('#paginator').append` to work with the code I gave you, so you'll instead need to add a span which looks something like `<span class="page" data-index="2">3</span>`. The data-index is for the pagination buttons NOT the articles

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have the basics

To get the total number of total pages you can simply do `var num = $('section>article').length;`

and

`$("#pagetotal").html(num);`

There's a few ways to make the pagination buttons work, personally I'd give them a data attribute and then a click event, like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //... Previous code

    $(".pagination > .page").click(function() {
        articles.eq(now).hide();

        now = $(this).attr("data-index");

        articles.eq(now).show();
    });
 });
```

So when you create your pagination numbers, put them all in a div called `.pagination` and give each page span a class of `.page` and give it an attribute called `data-index` with the given page index.

Comment: Thanks again you have been a great help I never had to do pagination with a total page count before. I wish I had done this 2 days ago I would be done already.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$(function() {
  var articles = $('section>article');
  var now = 0; // currently shown div
  var totalPages = articles.length;

  //Initialize
  articles.hide().first().show();
  $('#pagetotal').text(totalPages);
  $('#paginator').text(now+1);

  //handle page change
  $("a#next").click(function (e) {
    articles.eq(now).hide();
    now = (now + 1 < articles.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
    articles.eq(now).show(); // show next
    $('#paginator').text(now+1);
  });
  $("a#prev").click(function (e) {
    articles.eq(now).hide();
    now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : articles.length - 1;
    articles.eq(now).show(); 
    $('#paginator').text(now+1);
  });


});
```

Comment: Thanks Sam and Wilmer